# Can I use Layer Normalization with CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, normalization, data-processing, batch-normalization

I see the Layer Normalization is the modern normalization method than Batch Normalization, and it is very simple to coding in Tensorflow.
But I think the layer normalization is designed for RNN, and the batch normalization for CNN.
Can I use the layer normalization with CNN that process image classification task?
What are the criteria for choosing batch normalization or layer?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Layer normalisation` in CNNs, but i don't think it more 'modern' than `Batch Norm`. They both normalise differently. `Layer norm` normalises all the activations of a single layer from a batch by collecting statistics from every unit within the layer, while `batch norm` normalises the whole batch for every single activation, where the statistics is collected for every single unit across the batch.

`Batch norm` is generally preferred over `layer norm` as it tries to normalise every activation to a unit gaussian distribution, while `layer norm` tries to get the 'average' of all activations to unit gaussian. But if the batch size is too small to collect reasonable statistics, then `layer norm` is preferred.

Comment: Thanks your reply. If train samples are offset  from test samples for example brightness or rotation,  then layer norm is preferred, is ok?

Comment: Yes, for handling image inputs, you need to do to make the test and train data normalised. But `batch norm` and `layer norm` is for layers in between the networks that needs normalisation.

Answer (score 11):

I would also like to add, as mentioned in [original paper for Layer Norm, page 10 section 6.7](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/LayerNormalization.pdf), Layer Norm isn't advised to be used, and authors tell 'that more research has to be done' for CNNs

Also, a heads up - for RNN, Layer norm seems a better choice than Batch Norm, because training cases can be of different length in the same minibatch

Comment: This paper now is pretty old. Has this been further investigated?

Answer (score 8):

In more recent work [1], it was found that you can use LayerNorm in CNNs without degrading accuracy, though it depends on the model architecture.  Liu et al. [1] found while developing ConvNeXt that "Directly substituting LN for BN in the original ResNet will result in suboptimal performance" but they observed that their ConvNeXt "model does not have any difficulties training with LN; in fact, the performance is slightly
better".

It would be great if there were a better explanation as to why...

1. Liu et al. A ConvNet for the 2020s. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.03545.pdf