# How do I specify nn.LayerNorm without knowing the size of the dimensions?

Tags: pytorch

Usually when we do nn.Layernorm, we want to find the norm across that whole dimension, otherwise I think it would be called group norm. Why in the pytorch documents, they use LayerNorm like this?

```
>>> # Image Example
>>> N, C, H, W = 20, 5, 10, 10
>>> input = torch.randn(N, C, H, W)
>>> # Normalize over the last three dimensions (i.e. the channel and spatial dimensions)
>>> # as shown in the image below
>>> layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm([C, H, W])
>>> output = layer_norm(input)
```

What happens if I do not know the dimension size (C,H,W)? How do I define a LayerNorm layer?

Comment: This is a great question, no idea why anyone voted it down

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [post](https://wandb.ai/wandb_fc/LayerNorm/reports/Layer-Normalization-in-Pytorch-With-Examples---VmlldzoxMjk5MTk1) by wandb, they create a function to pre-calculate the image size during initialization and pass it to layerNorm.

But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941231/can-i-use-layer-normalization-with-cnn), it is not recommended to use LayerNorm with CNNs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).